# Input an object in ListAdapter in Android

Tags: android

I am new in android.

I have a list that must be viewed like this:
PIC   NAME   DESC

I have a list of buckets that contains all 3 info above.
The problem is, I can only make one field appear in the view. In this case, the bucket.getBucketName().

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        List<Bucket> buckets = BucketHandler.getBucketList();
        List<String> bucketList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Bucket bucket : buckets){
            bucketList.add(bucket.getBucketName());
        }
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row,
                R.id.bucket_list, bucketList));
    }
```

MY .xml is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">    

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/noData"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Row Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@color/lightgray">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/none"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bucket_list"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bucket_percentage"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:hidden_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I render all three fields inside the item list?
Thank you.

Comment: you can see [this](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) for creating custom Adapter for listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own custom adapter by extending ArrayAdapter and override getView () method